# OpenLayers 3 - Is there any quota limit like Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, openlayers, openlayers-3

**Google Maps Javascript API has a quota limit of 25.000 daily access and I wanna know if OpenLayers 3 has some limit either**.

I'm building an ionic 1 app and it works like a car tracker with a shared map between the users (each car will have his own device and the app will be running 20-24h/day, the device won't disconnect).
For now, my app gets my geolocation via Cordova Geolocation Plugin and make a server request via HTTP (interval of 10s). Then he makes another server request to get all the others cars' position and then create their individual markers on the map.
I've made some math and found out that those free 25k access/day shared between 10-20-N members won't be enough.

I liked Open Layers and wanted to give a chance, but I need to make sure I **won't have this usage limit** in case the application scalates to more than 5-10 users...

Comment: Note: Are you sure that Google Maps Javascript API limits to only 25? There are several limits based on the account you hold with Google

Comment: They say there's 25k FREE access limit per day.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=pt-br#usagelimits

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers is a mapping library, without data, there is no such limit for OpenLayers. You can even host it yourself ofcourse.

Comment: Google Maps has the base layers in it. OpenLayers doesn't ship with any data / base layers, but can be combined with other tile providers such as OSM, or Bing (with an API key). With the host part I meant that you can put the code on your own webserver, which you cannot do with Google Maps and that's how they check your usage limits.

Comment: Hmmm. That's what I need then, no usage limit. This way I can have 1 or 100 users using the same map at the same time without any problem, right? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers is open source. There is no usage limit. It is free, unlike Google/Bing etc...